# get response value from angular observable after POST method

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework

I am creating a `Recipe` object and saving it in my Django backend using `CreateAPIView`. After that `Recipe` is created I want to use its `id` value to create a Url redirect to another page where I can upload more information about the `Recipe` that was just created. I want to put the `id` value in the url because its easy to access it in the url, all i know how to do.

**AddRecipeComponent**

```
  submitrecipe(){
    this.recipeservice.addrecipe(this.newrecipe).pipe(
      map(res => this.response = res)
    )
    console.log(this.response) //THIS ALWAYS SHOW UNDEFINED IN THE CONSOLE
    this.router.navigate(['/recipeimage/'+this.response.id])
  }
}
```

**recipe.service**

```
  addrecipe(newrecipe):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(this.addrecipeUrl, newrecipe)
  }
```

**views.py**

```
class AddRecipe(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = RecipeFullSerializer
```

**serializer.py**

```
class RecipeFullSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ['name', 'id']
```

The problem is I cannot get the `id` parameter from the response in the `RecipeComponent`, I actually never see a value for response it is always 'undefined'. I know the observable is async, so thats probably why i always see it as undefined.

I think i need to wait for the asyn operation to complete? Or maybe there is a better way?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/3001761.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. HTTP POST call is an asynchronous method.
2. `subscribe()` is better that `map()` here. `map` is usually used to convert/map the response from one form to another.
3. All the response specific logic should be within the subscription.
4. It is also always good practice to handle the error when subscribing to HTTP calls.

Try the following

```js
submitrecipe() {
  this.recipeservice.addrecipe(this.newrecipe).subscribe(
    res => {
      this.response = res;
      console.log(this.response);
      this.router.navigate(['/recipeimage/'+this.response.id]);
    },
    error => {
      // handle error
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: ohhh it has to be in the subscription, thanks so much!!

Comment: If you're starting out with Angular I'd recommend you to go through https://angular.io/tutorial. It introduces lot of basics.